# Is $e$ "constructable" with the appropriate tools?

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

Of course $e$ cannot be constructed with straightedge and compass. If we allow a marked ruler or a non-rectractable compass (or we use origami...) we can construct numbers like $\sqrt[3]{2}$, but no trascendental numbers.
However the quadratrix of Hippias allows us to construct $\pi$, albeit using a special instrument.

I wonder if a similar instrument was ever devised to construct (in a finite number of steps) $e$.

Comment: A logarithmic spiral would probably work...

Comment: The answer is trivial without further details on what kind of tools you allow. For example, take a ruler with one marking in ratio $1:e$...

Comment: this would work, but I only know to draw an approximation of a logarithmic spiral :-(

Comment: @Wojowu: you should know in advance what the value of $e$ is, in order to build such a ruler.

Comment: Not an answer, but hopefully interesting: We can also talk about the problem of constructing a given number by representing it as an *area* or *volume*, etc. This is no harder than length representations (consider a $1\times x$ rectangle), but may be strictly easier (e.g. non-rectangular regions) - and the question may be formulated as, "What numbers are the integral of some 'nice' function over some 'nice' region?" For a very broad take on this question, look at the ring of **periods** (see http://www.ihes.fr/~maxim/TEXTS/Periods.pdf). It is widely conjectured that $e$ is *not* a period.

Comment: You said nothing about "building" an instrument. I interpreted this question as "is there some instrument which allows us...", and I gave an example of such instrument. If you want to prohibit this, make it explicit.

Comment: I bet you can build something based on f'-f=0. What about water flowing through a tube, where the diameter of the mouth of the tube varies with the amount of water passing through it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take two set squares without marks. Draw two marks on the edge of one of them and paste the ends of a moderately long, inextensible and with uniform mass distribution string over the marks.

Bisect the segment of the set square joining the two marks and mark that midpoint on the edge.

On a vertical $xy$-plane, use the other set square to transport the strung one parallel to the horizontal $x$-axis with the midpoint marked on the previous step over the $y$-axis. It will happen that the lowest point of the now hanging string will be over the $y$-axis and moving up or down this set square you can put it at $(0,1)$.

The equation describing the points of the string is $y=\cosh(x)$. Draw a vertical line passing through $(1,0)$. Mark the intersection of that line and the string at $(1,b)$.

It happens that $e = b + \sqrt{b^2 - 1}$ and you can construct this number in the usual way because you have already marked $(1,b)$.

Comment: it's a bit physical, but anyway even the quadratix of Hippias is so, and the idea of drawing $cosh(x)$ is quite ingenuous!

Comment: How do you construct a distance of 1? Or, if you don't, how do you locate (1, 0)?